# T-SQL: Need a way to sort NULLs to top of a resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, date

Scenario:

I have a simple `SELECT` query that retrieves data from a single table, sorted by a date field (the date field here indicates something like an "End date"). The application logic is that if this "end date" is a NULL, then the record indicates a current event. Now, these records are being displayed in a list that is sorted by this end date so that the ones that are the newest appear on top.

Obviously, since the NULL dated records are treated as "current" by the application, they need to be on top of this list of records. How do I get SQL Server 2012 to sort them to the top of the list? Note -- you can use pseudo (dummy) -values in ORDER BY, but you cannot select this pseudo value in the SELECT part.

Here is my current query (it does not handle the NULL, "ContractEndDate" is the date field we are interested in):

```
SELECT 
    [Id], [UserName], [ContractEndDate] 
FROM 
    [UserContracts] 
ORDER BY 
    [ContractEndDate] DESC
```

Any pointers would be useful.

Comment: When you use `Order By` for date column, `NULL` values will be in top anyway? so what the problem here

Comment: Its not doing that.. thats the problem. In my debug table, I have three rows where 2 of the date values are NULL and the third one is Jan 1, 2013. Expectation is to see NULL, NULL 1-1-2013. But when I run the above, I see 1-1-2013, NULL, NULL. Thats not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Add a primary order by criteria like:

```
order by case when ContractEndDate is null then 0 else 1 end, ContractEndDate
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer beacause it is very explicit in saying that nulls come first.

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT Id, UserName, ISNULL(ContractEndDate,GETDATE()) 
     FROM UserContracts 
     ORDER BY ISNULL(ContractEndDate,GETDATE()) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. This also matched an offline tip I got.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic order column and do order by based on that, and then by the date

```
;with CTE as (Select Id,Dt, (Case when Dt IS null then 0 else 1 end) OrderId
from Temp)

Select *
FRom CTE
Order by OrderId, Dt
```

Here is fiddle [sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c580c/1)

Comment: A little complicated. Got an offline tip to do an: ISNULL([ContractEndDate], GETDATE()). That worked fine. Your solution works too, so voting it up :-)

Comment: @SujaySarma: I though you don't need a default date to be selected when date is null :)

Comment: The ISNULL is in the ORDER BY and not in the SELECT. Like this:  SELECT Id, UserName, ContractEndDate
     FROM UserContracts 
     ORDER BY ISNULL(ContractEndDate,GETDATE()) DESC

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity, we can take a pseudo column which is the CASE statement here and order by this pseudo column.

```
SELECT 
[Id], [UserName], [ContractEndDate] 
FROM 
[UserContracts] 
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN [ContractEndDate] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), [ContractEndDate]    
DESC
```

Comment: Answers consisting of only code without explanation on why this solves the issue might be deleted in the review process. To prevent this, please add an explanation as to why and how this solves the issue.